# Using Powershell cmdlet in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powerapps

I've been attempting to use PowerShell PowerApps cmdlets (https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gdpr-admin-powershell-cmdlets/ ) in DevOps and failing. They work very well on the desktop but when I run them in a PowerShell task in DevOps it just always stalls, no error. It simply runs but never finished or reports an error. I'm sure there's some detail I'm missing I just do not know what. Can anyone help get me on the right track?

Comment: So for example if you run this powershell, what do you see in the logs: `Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=command]Testing powershell"`

Comment: I would suggest following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools . After creation of a Service Principal you could create a ServiceConnection in AzureDevops and depend on AzurePowershell task. Else create secret variable and use it with PowerShell task

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I get this back:
2021-08-09T06:31:24.2836583Z ##[error]Unable to process command '##vso[task.logissue type=command]Testing powershell' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
2021-08-09T06:31:24.2846958Z ##[error]issue type command is not an expected issue type.

Am I missing a dependency here?

Comment: @koushik yes I do use a service principal and MS's build tools for most tasks but haven't tried the AzurePowerShell task.

Comment: @LarsChristianJensen to log issues from Powershell, 

Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]There is a error"

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you used an interactive way to login with `Add-PowerAppsAccount`. In Azure DevOps pipeline, the interactive way is not supported.

In this case, your option is to install the modules with `-Force` and use a non-interactive way to login, e.g. as mentioned in the [blog](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gdpr-admin-powershell-cmdlets/).

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell -Force
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell -AllowClobber -Force

$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Username foo@bar.com -Password $pass
```

**Note:** Make sure the user account is not [MFA-enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks), otherwise you could not use it in the pipeline.

Comment: Worth a mention, this is a good approach when working with the public `PowerShell Gallery` but if using an internally-hosted gallery feed I would recommend marking the repository as trusted, provided public packages are not available through it.